# Blank pdf document

Tags: gnuplot, shell-escape

I entered the LaTeX `gnuplot` code exactly as stated in this site, which should output the sine curve on the output document using TeXworks compiler. It compiles but produces an empty document. An advice was to try `-shell-escape`.

I did the `-shell-escape` with no luck.  What else should I try?

This is the code that I entered in TexWorks. Compiled with both pdfLaTex and pdflatex+makeIndex+Bibtex

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex} % for MiKTeX,`pdflatex -shell-escape` enabled 
%\usepackage{gnuplottex} I have used this line to compile on TeXLive 2013
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf} % for MiKTeX,`pdflatex -shell-escape` enabled
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
plot [0:2*pi] sin(x) title 'Sine', cos(x) title 'Cosine'
\end{gnuplot}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: could you add your compilable code snippet? and Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Did you get any warnings or errors in TeXworks? What is the contents of your log file?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 1):

The code provide above is from 2013 Creating colourful plot using latex terminal of gnuplottex ?
Answer and should look like this in TeXworks

[image]

Actually its got some gnuplottex oddities compared to some other gnuplot calls. and I would change the Preamble to read something like this.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% gnuplot functions may not work if -aux-directory or  a /sub dir is set.
% The ".gnuplot" file(s) may be correctly written in the aux directory,
% but may not correctly pass through gnuplot to generate the ".table" file(s).
% there are some env vars for subdirectories read all the gnuplot docs

% WINDOWS TeX USERS need this option to pass `pdflatex -shell-escape` test (TeX Live & W32TeX not just MiKTeX)
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex} 

% a Linux / Mac entry for Tex Live or even MiKTeX on NON windows ?
%\usepackage{gnuplottex}  

% Gnuplottex example could do with an update to define use of gnuplot.exe (i.e. you must RENAME wgnuplot or pgnuplot)
% also how to \def\gnuplotexe{/opt/local/bin/gnuplot} for me on windows this worked just as well as using a script or path or editor setting
%\def\gnuplotexe{H:/gnuplot/gp530-20190105-win32-mingw/gnuplot/bin/gnuplot.exe}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf} % MiKTeX,`pdflatex -shell-escape` enabled (unknown if still needed in Windows ?)

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
plot [0:2*pi] sin(x) title 'Sine', cos(x) title 'Cosine'
\end{gnuplot}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The bottom line is that a blank page usually means gnuplot was not invoked by the use of \def\gnuplotexe{…} or by default in the shell to system paths. The best way to resolve this is ensure you have the latest gnuplot from http://www.gnuplot.info/ (I used v 5.3 for this run but the current release this year is 5.2.6.) Once installed then in TeXworks ensure that the gnuplotexe folder (. . ./gnuplot/bin) is included in the Typesetting Preference paths like this :-

[image]